# Combining an item from list with a list of tuples that have the same index positions

Tags: python

I have a list containing 640 items (all floats). I have a list of tuples (two items in the tuple) containing 640 items. Both lists are ordered and line up with each other. I want to take the two items from the tuple and put them at the top of their corresponding list of floats. For example, both of these are at index[0] of their corresponding lists.

```
[[37.0,
  40.1,
  '27.2',
  '58.3',
  '.467',
  '20.9',
  '40.2',
  '.519',
  '6.3',
  '18.1',
  '.349',
  '13.4',
  '19.2',
  '.698',
  '12.4',
  '19.5',
  '31.9',
  '15.2',
  '9.1',
  '6.9',
  '10.5',
  '15.5',
  '74.1']
```

```
 ('syracuse', 2012)
```

I want it to be one list ['syracuse', 2012, 37.0, 40.1, 27.2, etc] and do that to all 640 items.

Here's what I've tried so far.

```
empty_list = []
team_year = [list(x) for x in team_year]
for i,v in enumerate (cbb_team_sites):
    y = pd.read_html(v)[1]
    y = list((y.loc[0].T)[1:]) --> this is what produces the list of floats
    empty_list.append(y)

combined = list(zip(team_year,empty_list))
```

I've also tried:

`

```
for x in cbb_team_sites:
    y = pd.read_html(x)[1]
    y = list((y.iloc[0]).T)[1:]
    team_stats_list.append(y)
    for x in (range(640)):
        team_stats_list.append(team_year[x])
```

`

I'm sure there's an easy way to do this and I'm just missing it. But after about 4+ hours of trying, I figure it's time to ask for help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the last line in your first try with

```
combined = [list(t) + e for t, e in zip(team_year,empty_list)]
```

should work

Comment: Thank you, this worked just like I was looking for. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The `zip()` function can help you.

The `zip` built-in function mixes the elements of several iterables, combining those with the same index into a single group.

```
a = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
b = (1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9, 10.10)

print(tuple(zip(a, b)))
# ((1, 1.1), (2, 2.2), (3, 3.3), (4, 4.4), (5, 5.5), (6, 6.6), (7, 7.7), (8, 8.8), (9, 9.9), (10, 10.1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't ask a specific question, but based on your comment (**"I'm sure there's an easy way to do this and I'm just missing it."**), I infer that you are asking for an easier solution or help debugging your code.  I offer you the former.

```
# simplified example of data
a = [('syracuse', 2012), ('buffalo', 2022)]
b = [[1., 1.], [55., 55.]]

c = [[item[0], item[1]] for item in a]
[c[i] + b[i] for i in range(2)]
```

***Output***

```
     > [['syracuse', 2012, 1.0, 1.0], ['buffalo', 2022, 55.0, 55.0]]
```